# get each shift values group by python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, average

I working on the Production analysis data set(Shift-wise one(Day/Night)). Day shift is 7 AM-7 PM Aand Night Shift is 7 PM-7 AM.

1. **Sometimes** day & night shift can be divided into **two or more portions(ex:7AM-7PM Day shift can be - 7AM-10AM & 10AM-7PM).**
   If shifts are divided into two or more portions, **first need to check if the Brand is the same for that entire Shift partitions.**

**If YES**, set the start time as the beginning of the first shift start time partition and the End time as the end of the last shift end time partition.

For production: get the total production of the shift partitions

For RPM: get average of the shift partions

**If No**, get the appropriate values for each Brand.
(For more understanding, Please check the expected output.)

Sample of the Raw dataframe:

```
Start            end            shift   Brand   Production  RPM
7/8/2020 19:00  7/9/2020 7:00   Night   A       10          50
7/9/2020 7:00   7/9/2020 17:07  Day     A       5           50
7/9/2020 17:07  7/9/2020 17:58  Day     A       10          100
7/9/2020 17:58  7/9/2020 19:00  Day     A       5           60
7/9/2020 19:00  7/9/2020 21:30  Night   A       2           10
7/9/2020 21:30  7/9/2020 22:40  Night   B       5           20
7/9/2020 22:40  7/10/2020 7:00  Night   B       5           30
7/10/2020 7:00  7/10/2020 18:27 Day     C       15          20
7/10/2020 18:27 7/10/2020 19:00 Day     C       5           40
```

Expected Output:

```
Start           end             shift   Brand   Production  RPM
7/8/2020 19:00  7/9/2020 7:00   Night   A       10          50
7/9/2020 7:00   7/9/2020 19:00  Day     A       20          70
7/9/2020 19:00  7/9/2020 21:30  Night   A       2           10
7/9/2020 21:30  7/10/2020 7:00  Night   B       10          25
7/10/2020 7:00  7/10/2020 19:00 Day     C       20          30
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

Make sure the columns `Start` and `End` have datetime values (I've renamed `end` to `End` and `shift` to `Shift` :)):

```
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End'])
```

Then

```
df['Day'] = df['Start'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = (df.groupby(['Day', 'Shift', 'Brand'])
      .agg(Start = pd.NamedAgg(column='Start', aggfunc='min'),
           End = pd.NamedAgg(column='End', aggfunc='max'),
           Production = pd.NamedAgg(column='Production', aggfunc='sum'),
           RPM = pd.NamedAgg(column='RPM', aggfunc='mean'))
      .reset_index()[df.columns]
      .drop('Day', axis='columns'))
```

gives you

```
                Start                 End  Shift Brand  Production  RPM
0 2020-07-08 19:00:00 2020-07-09 07:00:00  Night     A          10   50
1 2020-07-09 07:00:00 2020-07-09 19:00:00    Day     A          20   70
2 2020-07-09 19:00:00 2020-07-09 21:30:00  Night     A           2   10
3 2020-07-09 21:30:00 2020-07-10 07:00:00  Night     B          10   25
4 2020-07-10 07:00:00 2020-07-10 19:00:00    Day     C          20   30
```

which seems to be your desired output (if I'm not mistaken).

If you want to transform the columns `Start` and `End` back to string with a format similar to the one you've given above (there's some additional padding):

```
df['Start'] = df['Start'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
df['End'] = df['End'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```